# adding field into Document with curl CouchDB without a new rev

Tags: couchdb, field, addition, couchdb-futon

I want to update or insert a filed in my document in CouchDB without a new rev number. Is that possible with curl ?

For example like Futon. If i open a document with futon and add a new field or update a filed its done without a new revision number. The changes are at the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Futon cannot do it either. It looks like Futon is no changing the rev number because it only updates the document (and changes the rev) when you hit *save*.

Everything is explained very well in [the Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/tour.html).

Comment: Thanks for you answer Simon. But now. I updated my document with Curl. But i have one Problem. If i opened my document I see a new revision number. Thats finde but all other fileds are not there. It is in the first rev. number but not at the second revision number. But I want to have all fields with the update in the second rev number too. Is there any opportunity ?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. You read the doc which contains the latest rev plus all the other fields, you add a field, then you save this updated document as a whole. You cannot append to a document, you replace it.

Comment: Futon works the same. When you it _save_, you have the full document in front of your eyes, not just the new fields.

Comment: simon i know. I opened futon and add a new field. Than i klick save the document. than i get a new rev. number. after this step i know that i see the full document and not only the new fields. 

But with curl its not the same. if i update my document with curl. I get a new rev. number and the new rev. number contains only the new field and not the full document. you know what i mean ? 

Its not the same like futon. Is there any opportunity to do it like futon with curl ?

Comment: Same thing with curl, you GET the document, then you PUT the updated document. I can't really help you beyond that but you can easily find [examples](http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/couchdbs-restful-api.html)…